# Dynamical systems on "non-rectangular" domains

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems

Consider the definition of a dynamical system as given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system#Formal_definition).

I am confused about why one needs to define the evolution function $\phi$ on a non-"rectangular domain", i.e. only on a subset $U\subseteq T \times X$ instead of directly on $T \times X$. In this regard I have a few questions:

- does the projection of $U$ on the first coordinate have to be a monoid?
- is it possible to give examples (as interesting/natural as possible), where it is really necessary to define the  evolution function $\phi$ on a $U$?

I tried playing around with some weird examples of dynamical systems (including taking $T$ to be the monoid of all real-real-valued functions together with composition---since this is not a group for which we just forget the group structure, so has an added element of weirdness :)---which naturally induce an evolution function), but I was not able to figure out sufficiently timely answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict the domain when the equation itself has singularities, like the Bessel equation
$$
xy''+y'-xy=0,
$$
or some (degree-) homogeneous equation
$$
y'=\frac{2x-3y}{3x-2y}.
$$
Or take gravity,
$$
\ddot {\bf q}_i=-\sum \mu_j\frac{{\bf q}_i-{\bf q}_j}{\|{\bf q}_i-{\bf q}_j\|^3}
$$
where you have to exclude the diagonals where ${\bf q}_i={\bf q}_j$.

Comment: Ok, so actually there are really natural examples that seem to illustrate the second bullet point. But what about the first?